How to make a generated sample to be parented to torso bone?
I have added a sample and parented it to the spine bone in the meta-rig:

Generated sample is parented to ORG-spine (that makes sense), but I want it to be parented to torso bone, that have no equivalent in the meta-rig.

Like hand bones can be parented to torso:

Can it be achieved without manual editing parent after regeneration?

What kind of sample is this? The "switching parent" feature depends on the Rig Type. The basic.pivot type for example has this feature.

I'm not decided it yet. I want to make a controller for the skirt of the jacket
